# PHP mail is not sending, but result is true

Tags: php, mailer

i use phpmailer for sending emails. in one script, the code works fine, in other exaple, result is true, but no mail is delivered. error log is empty, what would you recommend to check?
thanks

```
include_once '/var/www/xxxxxx.cz/web/php/phpmailer.php';
$to = 'dubcznic@gmail.com';
$to_name = '';
$from = 'robot@xxxxxx.cz';
$from_name = 'Robot';
$mail = new phpmailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddCC('nabytek-safr@xxxx.cz');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;     // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);      // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Import Robot Autronic';
$mail->Body = 'xxx';
$mail->AltBody = str_replace("<br />", "\n", 'xxx');
if (!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Mail Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo 'OK';
}

die();
```

Comment: It is important to note that just because the `mail()` function returns TRUE in php, it does not mean the mail will actually reach the intended recipient.  Returns of TRUE indicate an issue outside of the scope of the PHP script, perhaps spam filters for a clients email.

Comment: Check your mail log. Location depends on the MTA, but it's often in `/var/log/mail.log` or `/var/log/mail/`

Comment: @DerrickTucker He's not using `mail()`. He's using [PHPMailer's Send()](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/wp/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php.source.html#line380) which performs additional verification superior to `mail()`.

Comment: @MikeB Which still uses `mail()` unless SMTP or sendmail is specified

Comment: @MikeB I believe `Send()` does, in itself, use `mail()`.  Either way, the principle is the same.

Comment: @DerrickTucker and datasage, Ah I see now. I should have done some more digging before opening my mouth :)

Answer (score 0):

Check what text you are sending.  It could be that your results are being filtered out and put in a Spam folder.  Sometimes a mail with 'test' in the title could be sent right to Spam.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to verify that an email was delivered with PHP.

Check your mail server log (usually /var/log/mail) to see if the email was sent.

Send a BCC to an email address that you know has no spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate real emails with Telnet and MX records. See this answers
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17332773/468891

Answer (score 0):

First, check your spam, if you haven't already.

Second, change your SMTP settings to that of gmails, put your gmail log in and password and try.
If a mail fails to deliver you'll get an delivery- failure notification with possible causes of failure, which helps a lot. A delivery failure can also happen when no error is displayed in PHP.
This always helps me.